# Issue with storing image files for profile pictures

Tags: java, file

I'm doing a coursework project for university and I'm in charge of getting the profile system functioning. Our lecturer has given us some sample code to get a file-upload working which I'm going to use for the user's profile picture however even though my code looks to be very similar I just can't seem to get it working. The issue is that the file won't  actually create and save in my project, yet the code my lecturer gave me does!

Here is the code the lecturer gave me:

```
        NewsStory newsstory = new NewsStory();
        newsstory.uniqueid = "story_"+System.currentTimeMillis();
        newsstory.dateItWasPublished = System.currentTimeMillis();
        newsstory.title = toProcess.params.get("title");
        newsstory.description = toProcess.params.get("description");
        newsstory.journalists.add(toProcess.params.get("journalist"));
        newsstory.filepathToImage = toProcess.params.get("fileupload");

        File uploaded = new File(newsstory.filepathToImage);
        int ind = newsstory.filepathToImage.lastIndexOf('.');
        String extension = newsstory.filepathToImage.substring(ind);
        uploaded.renameTo(new File("httpdocs/"+newsstory.uniqueid+extension));
        newsstory.filepathToImage = newsstory.uniqueid+extension;
        //At this point you would normally add the newsstory to the database
        MVMap<String, NewsStory> newsStories = db.s.openMap("NewsStories");
        newsStories.put(newsstory.uniqueid, newsstory);
```

This basically takes in a String from a fileupload paramater passed in through a form and runs the code below. Here is my code:

```
                    user.userEmail = toProcess.params.get("email");
                    user.profilePicturePath = toProcess.params.get("filepath");

                    System.out.println(user.profilePicturePath);

                    File uploaded = new File(user.profilePicturePath);
                    int ind = user.profilePicturePath.lastIndexOf('.');
                    String extension = user.profilePicturePath.substring(ind);
                    uploaded.renameTo(new File("httpdocs/"+user.username+"ProfilePicture"+extension));
                    user.profilePicturePath = user.username+"ProfilePicture"+extension;
                    System.out.println(user.profilePicturePath);

                    users.put(user.username, user);
                    db.commit();
```

Does anyone know why I might be having this issue?

Comment: Hi Luke. Do you have any logs that you could share? Just as a shot in the dark - are you sure your form is `multipart/form-data` and the user who's running the server process has write permission for the target directory? Either of these conditions could cause the upload to fail.

Comment: @nstosic That was it! Thank you, my form wasn't multipart/form-data. Works amazingly now!